# Excel: Find match in sheet 1 and sheet 2, copy it in sheet 3

Tags: excel, vba

I need a function that will perform the following to track my "On hand" inventory in Excel 2007:

I have 3 sheets: "Inventory" , "On hand" and "Sales" with same column names:
A1= Style#  B1= Small  C1= Medium   D1= Large  E1= X-large
I have same amount of rows in "Inventory" and "On hand" but always different in "Sales".

What I would like is to have a function to do this:

1. copy and paste a row from "inventory" to "on hand" when I add new rows in the first one.
2. find the matching value in "on hand" and "sales" sheets for A1= Style# column
3. deduct B:E cells for matched row of "sales" and "on hand".

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A *function* can't do this. A *subroutine* can. #2 can be easily done with one or several of the `Match`, `Vlookup` and/or `Index` functions.  #1 and #3 don't really make much sense unless you can elaborate more. And bearing in mind that this is a *collaborative* site, don't expect a lot of help unless you're willing to post the code that you have tried so far and a more thorough explanation of your problem(s).

Comment: To clarify a *worksheet function* cannot do this. A regular non-worksheet function can do it as well as a sub can.

Comment: @TimWilliams  touché. :)

Comment: @David Zemens - I knew what you meant ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
If Sheets("Inventory").Cells(Rows.Count,"A").End(xlup).Row <> Sheets("On Hand").Cells(Rows.Count,"A").End(xlup).Row Then 
     For k = 1 to Sheets("Inventory").Cells(Rows.Count,"A").End(xlup).Row
         Sheets("On Hand").Range("A" & k & ":E" & k)=Sheets("Inventory").Range("A" & k & ":E" & k)
     Next k
End If

For i=1 to Sheets("Sales").Cells(Rows.Count,"A").End(xlup).Row
 For j=1 to Sheets("On Hand").Cells(Rows.Count,"A").End(xlup).Row
     If Sheets("Sales").Cells(i, "A") = Sheets("On Hand").Cells(j,"A") Then
         If Sheets("Sales").Cells(i, "B")<>"" then Sheets("On Hand").Cells(j,"B") = Sheets("On Hand").Cells(j,"B") - 1
         If Sheets("Sales").Cells(i, "C")<>"" then Sheets("On Hand").Cells(j,"C") = Sheets("On Hand").Cells(j,"C") - 1
         If Sheets("Sales").Cells(i, "D")<>"" then Sheets("On Hand").Cells(j,"D") = Sheets("On Hand").Cells(j,"D") - 1
         If Sheets("Sales").Cells(i, "E")<>"" then Sheets("On Hand").Cells(j,"E") = Sheets("On Hand").Cells(j,"E") - 1
     End If
 Next j
Next I
```

Mark as the up button if this post was helpful.

Comment: Thank you artis for your time. I tried to add the code to my worksheet but every time I got a compile error as following: compile error: invalid outside procedure

xlUp

Answer (score 0):

You can start with No 1 .. In your Sheet "Inventory"

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  Sheets("OnHand").Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column) = Target.Value
End Sub
```